# Jquery multimedia slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, multimedia

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to create a web ready/embedable image and audio slideshow? Each image slide has to have it's own audio clip and users would be able to move between slide at any time. I am trying to create an interactive slideshow for my website.

I would like to do something like this:

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/picturegalleries/9522385/British-rock-climbers-conquer-the-east-face-of-Cerro-Autana-in-Venezuela.html?frame=2329368

but with audio on each slide. It doesn't have to play automatically but just give the user an option to play the audio attached to the slide or navigate to the next slide. I have searched the web but most multimedia slideshows only have continuous audio over the whole show.

Can this be achieved in some kind of software, javascript or jquery? Any help or guidance in the right direction would be great. Thanks in advance.